# Search file contents recursively and display sorted by date modified

Tags: grep, find, zsh

I am trying to set up a file search which fulfils all of the following:

1. Search recursively within a directory which includes wildcards (ex: /home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/ ... should search within "level_5" and all its subdirectories)
2. Search contents of a file (ex: "text in file")
3. Define a filename to search (ex: script.js) (might be able to be combined with #1?)
4. Display results with path and context of search string (ex. `/home/user/level_1/level_2/level_3/level_4/level_5/script.js Here is the text in file` ... exact format can be different but should contain this information. Timestamp is not required. Would be a bonus if instead of the full path, it only displayed the directory which is represented by `level_2` in the example above, but it's not a requirement.)
5. Display results sorted by file modified date, from oldest to newest.

I have this command below which fulfils 1-4.

`grep -r --include=\script.js "text in file" /home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/`

Any ideas to include the 5th? I've seen various explanations to accomplish similar things with `find` or using zsh but I've not been able to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `zsh`, it should just be a matter of:

```
grep -H 'text in file' /home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/**/script.js(.Om)
```

Where `**/` matches any level of subdirectories, the `.` qualifier restricts to *regular* file (like GNU `grep` does with `-r`), and `Om` `O`rders in reverse by `m`odification time (like `ls -rt`). Add the `D` qualifier if you also want to look for hidden ones (like GNU `grep`'s `-r` does).

`-H` (a GNU extension, like `-r` or `--include`) makes sure the file name is printed even if only one file is found by `zsh`.

To print the *level 2 directory* instead of the file path, still with GNU `grep`, you can do:

```
for f (/home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/**/script.js(N.Om))
  grep -H --label=${f:h5:t} 'text in file' < $f
```

Where `:h5` takes 5 *`h`ead* components (the `/home/user/level_1/level_2` in `/home/user/level_1/level_2/and/more...`), and `:t` the *`t`ail* of that (`level_2`).

To also include the timestamp, you can use zsh's `stat` builtin to retrieve it:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (/home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/**/script.js(N.Om)) {
  stat -LF%FT%T.%3.%z -A t +mtime $f
  grep -H --label="${f:h5:t} ($t)" 'text in file' < $f
}
```

Here with timestamps formatted in their standard unambiguous format with ms precision like 2022-12-01T09:30:00.895+0000, but you can adapt the format to your liking with `-F` (uses `strftime()` formatting).

Comment: Brilliant! Adding `(.Om)` worked! Many thanks. 

I don't seem to be able to get `--label` to work. Copying the second command exactly, but replacing the label with `--label=test` still displays the filename. Any thoughts of what might be missing?

Comment: Figured it out. Seems we needed `<` before `$f`. `for f (/home/user/level_1/*/level_3/*/level_5/**/script.js(.Om)) grep -H --label=${f:h5:t} 'text in file' < $f`. Now label does show the `level_5`. I'm thrilled with this!!

Comment: @Alvin. Indeed. My bad. Fixed now thanks